# How do I parse information from netstat?

Tags: sed, ip, netstat, conky, port

How do I extract the following from the output of `netstat -anp`?

- remove ip address
- remote port
- local application name
- local port
- PID

I need this information to run in my conky. It shows everything, but the last digit of PID number is missing. I do not understand the `sed` command. Please help.

The command as follows:

```
netstat -anp | grep 'ESTABLISHED' | sed -r 's|.*192.[0-9.]+:([0-9]*)\s*([0-9.]+):([0-9]+)[^ESTABLISHED]+\ESTABLISHED ([0-9]*)[^/]+/([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)|\5 \2 \1 \3 \4|' | awk '{printf("%-14s %-15s %8s %6s %8s\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5)}'
```

Please you should have open ESTABLISHED connections (e.g., with firefox) to show correct command output.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this part of the sed pattern:

```
([0-9]*)[^/]+/
```

it captures any number of digits 0..9, then at least 1 character that is not a  slash "/", then a "/".  This is trying to match a string such as

```
ESTABLISHED 2783/firefox
```

Initially, it matches `2783`, but then has to remove the final digit, 3, in order to comply with the *not a slash*.

The fix is to replace the `+` by a `*`, to allow for zero matches:

```
([0-9]*)[^/]*/
```

Comment: To Andy Dalton and to meuh: Thank you very much for your time, effort and perfect answer. Now it works perfectly. Thank you very much. Stackexchange.com is great community.